Why am I getting 'package does not exist' error even though the module and path are correct?
Question: I am trying to use the following code with com.dd.plist package:
import com.dd.plist.NSArray;
import com.dd.plist.NSDictionary;
import com.dd.plist.XMLPropertyListWriter;

public class Test1 { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example: Using NSDictionary
        NSDictionary dict = new NSDictionary();
        dict.put("key", "value");
        
        // You can print or work with the dictionary contents.
        System.out.println(dict);
    }
}

However, I’m getting errors like "package com.dd.plist does not exist" when trying to run the code. I’ve already added the correct paths to my build.gradle file, but it’s still not working.
Here’s the relevant sourceSets configuration in my build.gradle:
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {       
            srcDirs = ['C:/vscode/test1/app/src/main/java', 'C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/dd-plist-master/src/main/java/com/dd/plist']
        }
    }
}

Despite having the paths correctly set, why is this import still causing an error? Could there be something else I missed?
I've correctly configured the module and path, and I expected to be able to use the imported modules without any issues

Change 'C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/dd-plist-master/src/main/java/com/dd/plist' to 'C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/dd-plist-master/src/main/java' in your build.gradle file.

"Despite having the paths correctly set ..."  - except that you haven't set them correctly.  It is not a good idea to assume that you have done something correctly if you are getting unexpected problems.  (Just 'cos you believe something doesn't necessarily make it true.)

C:\vscode\test1\dd-plist-master, C:\vscode\test1\app\src\main\java\test1.java
Each file is arranged like this. How do I link two sources?

Okay, so now the build.gradle code is like this. sourceSets {
main {
java {
srcDirs = ['C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/dd-plist-master/src/main/jav', 'app/src/main/java']
    }

   
}

}

Erm ... "jav" ?  Should be "java".  You really need to be >>accurate<< when you are 1) changing configs and 2) posting on StackOverflow.   When I said to change the 2nd entry on the srcDirs path, I >>didn't<< say to change the first one.  Put the first entry back to what it was before ... assuming that the base path is correct.

Thank you. Even after fixing it, there are still, errors The import com.dd cannot be resolvedJava(268435846)
sourceSets {
main {
java {
srcDirs = ['C:/vscode/test1/dd-plist-master/dd-plist-master/src/main/java', 'app/src/main/java']
    }

   
}

}

Put the "app/src/..." entry back to how it is in the question.  Like I said in my last comment.

OK.  So now I am really confused.  Why are you trying to configure one Gradle project to pull in >>source files<< from a different project?   If you are going to split your code into two projects like that, they should have separate build files, and the "app" project should refer to the classes in "dd-plist-master" via the latter project's JAR articfacts, or whatever.
